# Adding scattered data to a pie chart through VBA trouble

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I'm working on a project for my thesis and I am facing an error when I try to plot a pie chart in excel using VBA.

The nature of the data I'm working with prevents me from using straight ranges as the data is scattered on the worksheet.

```
obseg(0) = "=List3!"
obseg(1) = "=List3!"
Range("K6").Select
Do Until completed
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    'Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    If (ActiveCell.Value = "Čas:") Then
        obseg(0) = obseg(0) & CStr(ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Address) & ";List3!"
        obseg(1) = obseg(1) & CStr(ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 1).Address) & ";List3!"
    End If
    If (IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value)) Then
        obseg(0) = obseg(0) & CStr(ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Address)
        If (IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 1).Value)) Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 1).Value = "neznana"
            obseg(1) = obseg(1) & CStr(ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 1).Address)
        Else
            obseg(1) = obseg(1) & CStr(ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 1).Address)
        End If
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
```

This is the code that collects this data and writes a string into obseg(0) and obseg(1).
The result of a particular run gives this result for obseg(0):

```
=List3!$K$19;List3!$K$63;List3!$K$69;List3!$K$79;List3!$K$114;List3!$K$118;List3!$K$122;List3!$K$126;List3!$K$136;List3!$K$142;List3!$K$145
```

This is the exact same string that I get, when selecting the same data by hand and running macro recorder. That code then works, this doesn't. The problem occurs when creating a new chart by code.

```
Charts.Add
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlPie
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).values = obseg(0)
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = obseg(1)
```

This returns and error, stopping at the third line:

```
Runtime error '1004'
Application-defined or object-defined error
```

And explanation of why this is happening or any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Correction: Apparently the code generated by the macro recorder also doesn't work. Is there any way to get the pie chart to accept the string of data I am receiving?

Comment: A pie chart has one series only, so you need to clear any existing series first. Pie is also generally not the best choice of chart type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use a string for `Series.Values` and `Series.XValues`. Use a `Union` of Ranges instead.

Simple Example:

```
Sub Makro1()

    Set oXValues = Worksheets("List3").Range("$B$2:$B$4")
    Set oXValues = Union(oXValues, Worksheets("List3").Range("$B$8:$B$10"))
    Set oXValues = Union(oXValues, Worksheets("List3").Range("$B$13:$B$14"))

    Set oValues = Worksheets("List3").Range("$C$2:$C$4")
    Set oValues = Union(oValues, Worksheets("List3").Range("$C$8:$C$10"))
    Set oValues = Union(oValues, Worksheets("List3").Range("$C$13:$C$14"))

    Set oChart = Charts.Add
    oChart.ChartType = xlPie
    oChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    oChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""test"""
    oChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = oValues
    oChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = oXValues

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working by constructing the obseg strings in a completely different ways. Turns out that pie charts accept only numerical data as the first serie and any type as the second serie.

For those interested here is the new code that collects the data from the spreadsheet:

```
obseg(0) = "={"
obseg(1) = "={"
Range("K6").Select
Do Until completed
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    'Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    If (ActiveCell.Value = "Čas:") Then
        obseg(0) = obseg(0) & CStr(ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value) & "; "
        obseg(1) = obseg(1) & Chr(34) & CStr(ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 1).Value) & Chr(34) & "; "
    End If
    If (IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value)) Then
        obseg(0) = obseg(0) & CStr(ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value) & "}"
        If (IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 1).Value)) Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 1).Value = "neznana"
            obseg(1) = obseg(1) & Chr(34) & CStr(ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 1).Value) & Chr(34) & "}"
        Else
            obseg(1) = obseg(1) & Chr(34) & CStr(ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 1).Value) & Chr(34) & "}"
        End If
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
```

The result of a particular run fills the array obseg(1) with:

```
={"1"; "5"; "12"; "neznana"}
```

And obseg(0) with:

```
={265; 76; 857; 8444}
```

The pie chart accepts this.

Fort Ash

Comment: But so the chart is totally independent of the data on the sheet. If the data changes on the sheet, the chart will not change until you run the macro again.